# $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME remains empty after set in previous stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ci.yml

I have the following GitLab pipeline. For brevity I have removed some code. In `deploy-dev` stage I am creating environment `dev`. Then in the next stage `test-postdeploy` I am using `$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME` to set the `base_url` variable value. However, in `test-postdeploy` stage the `$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME` always empty

```
stages:
  deploy:dev
  deploy:qa
  deploy:prod
  test:postdeploy

deploy-dev:  
  image: node
  stage: deploy:dev
  environment: 
    name: dev
  script:
    - . deploy/scripts/deploy-dev.sh
  rules: 
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "dev"

deploy-qa:  
  image: node
  stage: deploy:qa
  environment: 
    name: qa
  script:
    - . deploy/scripts/deploy-qa.sh
  rules: 
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "qa"

deploy-prod:  
  image: node
  stage: deploy:prod
  environment: 
    name: prod
  script:
    - . deploy/scripts/deploy-prod.sh
  rules: 
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "release"


test-postdeploy:
  tags:
    - xlarge
  image: node
  stage: test:postdeploy  
  variables:
    base_url: "" 
  script:
    - echo "$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME"    // this is empty
    - script/postdeploy-test.sh
  rules: 
    - if: $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME == "dev"
      variables:
        base_url: "https://dev.example.com"
    - if: $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME == "qa"
      variables:
        base_url: "https://qa.example.com"
    - if: $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME == "prod"
      variables:
        base_url: "https://prod.example.com"
```

**UPDATE 1**
I can probably pass environment name to another stage using  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job
However, this does not make sense. Environment Name is most basic value that any ci/cd pipeline would need to know. The `CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME`
variable should be available in all stages once its set without doing some extra work.

Comment: You have not set the environment in the `test-postdeploy` job so `$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME` will not be set

Comment: I set the environment name is `deploy-dev` stage..isnt pipeline automatically then sets the
$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME

Comment: I have environment specific deployment `stage` which sets the environment name.  So assumption is down the line stages can use the $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME and do specific things related to that environment.

Comment: It only sets the environment for that Job not for the entire pipeline. So when your test job runs it runs in its own context it wouldn't know about the environment you sent in another job. That's not how it works